# "Not in keyof" in Typescript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Creates a type where each property from `Type` is now of type `boolean`:

```
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: boolean;
};
```

Now I want to extend this: All properties **not in** `Type`, if present, must be of type `string`. Something like this:

```
type OptionsFlags<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Type]: boolean;
  [Property not in keyof Type]?: string;
};
```

What is the correct approach to this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without a helper function.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Btw., I was thinking about Conditional Types (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but couldn't make it work. Something like this: `[prop]: prop in Type ? boolean : string` (edit: the ladder is obviously pseudo syntax ^^)

Comment: I guess that [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEPGbW) is the closest you can get

Comment: What is `T`? You're defining `f<T>(...)` and call it with `f(...)`. Thank you

Comment: `T` is the type of the object I am passing to `f()`. It gets automatically inferred

Comment: I finally get it. Thank you! I am not sure whether I like it or accept this cause this looks pretty oversized for such "basic" requirement. :x You can post this as an answer and I will accept it unless there's a better solution coming in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stand-alone type will probably not work here. What you are looking for is basically this:

```
type OptionsFlag<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: boolean
} & {
  [K in Exclude<string, keyof T>]: string
}
```

But this does not work (yet) in TypeScript. Because `Exclude<string, keyof T>` evaluates down to `string` and will be an index signature. You can not construct an object with this type because every property's type will have to fulfill both index signature requirements `string & boolean` which is not possible.

The only work-around I could think of is this:

```
type Type = {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: string
}

type OptionsFlag<T, S> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof S ? boolean : string
}

function f<T>(obj: OptionsFlag<T, Type>) {}

f({
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: "abc", // error because c is in Type and string
  d: "abc",
  e: "abc",
  f: true   // error because f is not in type and boolean
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=3&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKpWBeGBvYMYEMBcMDOIATgJYB2A5hjAEZ6GmXUDG9x5VAvsKIjAPIQQJAPZl8AMQA2WCgB44AGhgBlAHwwU6TAG0A0jHIwA1lDAiAZvAC6eA1AAeIKGQAm%20E2cuqYAfloiIlJQWGQwbIxcPBYArmTMwmIwFgpqABQiNABWeIKJ4tKyCsoI0GoAlGjcwBZp2th4xDFQitR0ME0tLHgARFg0zD3KAPTDMFBERCJEtFDMWDH4sMyGHkalsKGuBOxMmK69-YOtmFCHA0PUFo1EzZgwo%20OT07Pzi7BWJB5kIiCGYeBoNg3AEgiEyMBOOUgA)

We can use a generic type of a function to map over each property of the passed type `T`. We then check for each property of `T` if it belongs to `S` and ajust the type accordingly.

This has a major drawback: The type of `S` must be known when we declare the function. As you can see, I put the type `Type` in `OptionsFlag<T, Type>` in the function declaration instead of using a second generic type. TypeScript does not yet support partial type inference, so we can't let TypeScript infer `T` and manually specify a second generic type when we call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since the mapped type can only access keys live within Type, you need to provide an extra Generic Type for comparison.

```
type OptionsFlags<T extends {}, K extends string> = {
  [k in K]: k extends keyof T ? boolean : string;
};
```

Comment: That `k` is a type parameter and thus is conventionally written as an uppercase letter (so maybe `P`, which is for Property, and is the conventional thing to use when `K` for Key is unavailable)